How to create a Y4M file that generates an all-zero payload RTP traffic?
I am currently trying to run some experiments to test a C++ WebRTC application. This app uses the Y4mFileGenerator class to sample frames from a given y4m video file. For the sake of comparing its performance to another (simpler) application that only sends zero-ed RTP packets, I thought the fastest way was to find (or generate?) a y4m video file that would produce all-zero RTP traffic, and plug it into the same Y4mFileGenerator.
Since I am not familiar with video formats in general, I am not sure what to look for in terms of the content of that raw y4m file, if there are readily available options and how to generate one if needed.
Any hint would be greatly appreciated :)
